# Свой список C++

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

Есть список MyList. Мне нужно чтобы в методе addItem вызывался копирующий конструктор класса у объекта переданного в метод addItem, а не только класса родителя T. Как это можно сделать?

```
template <class T>
MyList {
...
  //метод получает объект класса T и производные от него
  void addItem(T& item) {
    ...
    node.x = new T(item);
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Если вы делаете `new T(item);`, то вы создаете объект именно типа `T` и вызываться будет конструктор именно типа `T`. Никаких других вариантов тут быть не может. Поэтому не надо рассказывать что вам "нужно, чтобы вызывалось". Рассказывайте, что именно нужно сделать. Что вам нужно хранить в своем списке?

Comment: Подумайте о том, чтоб хранить не элементы класса, а указатели на них. Или нужны обходные пути - типа виртуального метода типа `Clone`, который будет создавать копию соответствующего типа.

Comment: Нельзя ли компилятор попросить создать для каждого наследника класса T реализацию функции addItem которая вызывает копирующий конструктор необходимого класса?

Comment: Можно. А дальше что? Если ваш список хранит именно объекты типа `T`, то какой вам смысл конструировать наследников, если сохранить их в списке вы все равно не сможете? Показывайте устроство самого списка. Не видя деталей устроства списка осмысленного ответа не дать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то вы натолкнули на решение.

Делаем ваш метод добавления шаблонным. Что-то [вроде](https://ideone.com/JjEyuh)

```
template<typename T>
class myList
{
    T* data[3];
public:
    template<typename U>
    void add(int i, const U& u)
    {
        data[i] = new U(u);
    }
    void out()
    {
        for(const auto& p: data) p->out();
    }
};

struct Base
{
    virtual void out() { cout << "Base\n"; }
};

struct D1: public Base
{
     void out() { cout << "D1\n"; }
};

struct D2: public D1
{
    void out() { cout << "D2\n"; }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    myList<Base> m;
    Base b;
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
    m.add(0,b);
    m.add(1,d1);
    m.add(2,d2);
    m.out();
}
```

Код максимально упростил, чтоб показать саму идею. Его можно снабдить проверками, например, что добавляется именно наследник или иной функциональностью. Но идея должна быть понятна.